# Element positioned higher because of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two identical divs and one of them is nested inside an extra `<div class="flexbox">`. In display, both of the squares sit besides to their peer paragraph, but the first square is higher compared to the second one to their respective paragraph. What effect of flexbox creates the difference?

```css
p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.85rem;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>
    <div id="first" class="square">A square</div>
    <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="second" class="square">A square</div>
  <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
</div>
```

Without the `line-height` and `margin-top`, the square inside the flexbox is still higher, and I'd like to demolish that side-effect of flexbox.

Comment: Set `margin: 0;` to your `p` and set the same `line-height` in your `p` and `.square`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of **margin collapsing**.

*From MDN:*

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.
>
> <sup>*source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing*</sup>

In your non-flexbox example the `margin-top` of the child div and the `margin-top` of the container div are collapsed into one margin. This is consistent with margin collapse behavior between parent and child in a *block formatting context*.

Note that div elements normally have a `margin-top` by default which is applied by the browser. Look for it in dev tools in *user agent styles*.

You can override the margin collapse behavior by adding a **border** or **padding** on the container:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

#border {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

#padding {
  padding: 5px;
}

.square {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: #cfc;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.85rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>
    <div id="first" class="square">A square</div>
    <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="border">
  <div id="second" class="square">A square</div>
  <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
</div>

<div id="padding">
  <div id="second" class="square">A square</div>
  <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
</div>
```

In a *flex formatting context*...

> ...the flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> <sup>*source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers*</sup>

Hence, there is no margin collapsing in flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `div#first.square` doesn't have the same line-height as `<p>` sitting right next to it.

```css
p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.85rem;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.square {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.85rem;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>
    <div id="first" class="square">A square</div>
    <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="second" class="square">A square</div>
  <p>A paragraph sits aside to the square.</p>
</div>
```

BTW you should use dev tools. It makes debug a lot of other things much easier.
[image: Devtools screenshot]

Comment: I understand that the squares aren't in the same line-height as the paragraph, and I would like to know how to let that square which is inside the flexbox not raise itself, for the reason of consistency. And thanks for the tip of using dev tools! I'll pay more attention to them.